# Heroku Router logging request but Dyno not receiving it

Tags: heroku

We have an interesting situation where a request sent from CCBill payment processing to our Heroku app is not reaching the dyno

The log looks something like this with just a heroku[router] entry and nothing from the dyno.

> 2017-09-08T17:14:38.373492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/link?clientAccnum=95&clientSubacc=0001&eventType=NewSaleSuccess&eventGroupType=Subscription" host=www.ourhost.net request_id=0b587a94-fdb8-4a8c-9e31 fwd="unknown,64.38.241.33" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=301 bytes=264 protocol=http

This POST request is sent on a successful sale. However, our server end point does not seem to be processing the request.

I have tried the same link with a REST client tool and can confirm that instead of just the herok[router] handling the request, we also saw dyno[web1] actually start processing it. The log showed the dyno entry in addition to the router one like we see above.

Any thoughts on why the real request sent from CCBill on a successful sale  wouldn't make it to the dyno while a fake one does?

Does Heroku Block IP ranges?
Are there rules on the router that would prohibit the request from hitting the dyno?

Any thoughts would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the status is 301, which is a redirect, and the URL does not have a trailing slash before the query string. That is default Django behavior - can you verify your settings, as indicated here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: Thank you. I think the redirect is because we have the request coming in over http and there is a 301 to https (maybe ?)

Comment: You could also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#ssl-https In either case, though - you need to know whether the CCBill understands and processes redirects correctly. If not, then you have to make sure it is sending a proper request that won't get redirected.